# How to generate multiple SVG plots dependent on incoming JSON

Tags: javascript, json, django, d3.js, radar-chart

My end goal is to create something like this:

[image: Mock up]

- The Timeseries shows total sales per department over time
- The slider (red) selects a month of interest that drives the radar plots
- The radar plot(generated for each Job Role) show the data for the specific month, broken out to show sales per department per Job Role (over time)

My timeseries chart is working correctly (loading from a csv file).

**However, I am now stumped at how to:**

1. Dynamically generate as many SVGs as are required from the incoming JSON array.

The javascript/D3 code I have is based on [Alan Dunning's Radar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/4c36eb1abdb248de34c64f5672afd857) and [Mike Bostocks Multi-Series Line Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

This is the structure of my master DataFrame that I have to work with:

```
colIndex=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['New York','Paris'],
                                     ['Electronics','Household'],
                                     ['A','B','C'],
                                     ['Junior','Senior']],
                                    names=['City','Department','Team','Job Role'])

rowIndex=pd.date_range('25-12-2017',periods=12,freq='D')

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 24), index=rowIndex, columns=colIndex)
df1.index.name='Date'
```

[image: Source DataFrame]

**Update: My Django view for loading the timeseries plot (from CSV):**

```
def visual(request, storeCode):
    s = get_object_or_404(Store, store_code=storeCode)

    # ...other code to build lists: store, Department, Team, Role, SalesData ...
    arrays=[store, Department, Team, Role]                                               #Make a list of lists for the sales components
    tuples= list(zip(*arrays))                                                                     #Zip the list-of-lists into a tuple for each sales Series
    sales=pd.concat(salesData, axis=1)                                                             #Concatenate the Series' into a dataframe
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Store','Category','Task','Role'])              #Give a name to each level of the columnar Multi-Index
    sales.columns=index                                                                            #Apply the names to the columnar Multi-Index
    sales.index.name='date'
    sales = sales.apply(pd.to_numeric)                                                             #Convert all Series' to floats

#Save master file to pickle (where it gets picked up by radar plot view)
with open(s.store_code + '.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(sales, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    salesByMonth=sales.sum(axis=1, level=[1]).resample('M').sum()                                  #Get totals for column index[0]
    salesByMonth.index.name="date"
    salesByMonth.to_csv('myApp/static/myApp/salesMONTH.csv', date_format='%Y%m%d')

    uniqueRoles=set(Role)

    return render(request, 'myApp/visual.html', {
        'store': s,
        'roles': ",".join(uniqueRoles),
    })
```

**Update: My Django view for the radar plot(s) (from JSON):**

```
def API_roles_month(request, storeCode):
    salesRolesByDay=pd.read_pickle(storeCode+'.pickle')
    data2=salesRolessByDay.resample('M').sum().stack([1,3]).reorder_levels([2,0,1]).sum(axis=1).sort_index()
    data2.name='Sales'
    data3=data2.reset_index()
    data4=data3.to_json(orient='records')

    return JsonResponse(data4, safe=False)
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that Django knows exactly how many months are in your DataFrame (which is a `pandas.DataFrame` I assume). So the template code could include all required json data broken down into months and the JS code would switch dataset. Is that an option you're open to?

Comment: Absolutely - I'd be open to anything! :-) I tried passing variables (both JSON and python lists) to the template but they seemed to be getting masked so thought it wasn't possible. Thanks in advance for any insights here!

Comment: Could you show the current view code that renders this template? Then we have a bit of an idea what we're working with. Also a trimmed version of `df3.to_json()`. Mostly to see where the month comes into play.

Comment: Thansk @Melvyn - I've updated the question at the end with my views and `to_json()` call. I'm new to D3 (as is no doubt obvious!) so if there is a more natural way to approach I'm happy to go back and start again...!